# printing report to PDF based on each record in query

Tags: vba, pdf, report

I have a query in Access (Q_Invoices) that has separate records based on the invoice number (Invoice_Number). I also have a report that is linking to this query (R_Invoices_PDF). What I would like to do is to have VBA code to loop through each record in the query, and print the record as a separate PDF from the report.

I copied the following code from some website, and tried to adapt it for my purposes. It works to an extent. However, I stop it before it loops, and it saves all the records, not just the first one.

```
Private Sub cmd_GenPDFs_Click()
    Dim rs                    As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sFolder               As String
    Dim sFile                 As String

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    sFolder = "D:\Documents\Orchestra\Invoices\Invoice files\"

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Invoice_Number FROM Q_Invoices", dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
            
            DoCmd.OpenReport "R_Invoices_PDF", acViewPreview, , "[Invoice_Number]=" & ![Invoice_Number], acHidden
            sFile = Nz(![Invoice_Number], "") & ".pdf"
            sFile = sFolder & sFile
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "R_Invoices_PDF", acFormatPDF, sFile,  acExportQualityPrint
            'If you wanted to create an e-mail and include an individual report, you would do so now
            DoCmd.Close acReport, "R_Invoices_PDF"
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

    Application.FollowHyperlink sFolder    'Optional / Open the folder housing the files

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
    End If
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then    'Let's ignore user cancellation of this action!
        MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Source: cmd_GenPDFs_Click" & vbCrLf & _
               "Error Description: " & Err.Description & _
               Switch(Erl = 0, "", Erl <> 0, vbCrLf & "Line No: " & Erl) _
               , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    End If
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub
```

Comment: _I stop it before it loops, and it saves all the records, not just the first one._ If "saves" means "prints as PDF", it is probably what you intent to do ... but apparently _by magic_, since you "stop it before it loops". This makes no sense.

Comment: What I meant was, I run it line by line by pressing F8, in order to test the code. Before it loops, I check what's happened, and it has saved all the invoice records to one PDF file. I want a separate PDF for each record. There's obviously no point allowing the code to continue, as it's not working as intended. Does this make sense to you now?

Comment: By the way, isn't "print to PDF" and "save to PDF" synonymous?

Answer (score 0):

I recall some issue with filtering the report. Thus, we filter the query that drives the report to return only data for a single invoice using a `TempVars`.

Here, *Faktura* means *Invoice*:

```vb
Private Sub FakturaPrint( _
    ByVal PrintType As CdPrintType, _
    Optional ByRef FullPath As String)

    Const ReportName    As String = "Faktura"
    Const FileNameMask  As String = "Faktura{0}.pdf"
    Const FileIdMask    As String = "kladde Job {0}"
    Const CancelError   As Long = 2212  ' Cactus TimeSag cannot print the object.
    Const PrintError    As Long = 2501  ' PrintOut was cancelled.
    
    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim FileId          As String
    Dim PrintCount      As Integer
    Dim PrintCopy       As Integer
    
    On Error GoTo FakturaPrint_Click_Error
        
    ' Set filter on the source query of the report.
    TempVars("FakturaID").Value = Me!FaktID.Value
    
    Select Case PrintType
        Case cdPrintPreview
            DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal
        Case cdPrintPrinter
            PrintCount = Nz(Me!UdskFakt.Column(2), 1)
            If PrintCount < 1 Then
                PrintCount = 1
            End If
            For PrintCopy = 1 To PrintCount
                DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewNormal, , , acWindowNormal
            Next
        Case cdPrintPdf
            Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"
            FileId = Nz(Str(Me!Faktura.Value), Replace(FileIdMask, "{0}", Me!JobID.Value))
            FileName = Replace(FileNameMask, "{0}", FileId)
            ' Return FullPath by reference for e-mail.
            FullPath = Path & FileName
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF, FullPath, False, , , acExportQualityPrint
    End Select
        
FakturaPrint_Click_Exit:
    Me!TextForClipboard.SetFocus
    Exit Sub

FakturaPrint_Click_Error:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case CancelError, PrintError
            ' Printing cancelled by user.
            ' Ignore.
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure FakturaPrint_Click of Sub Form_Faktura"
    End Select
    Resume FakturaPrint_Click_Exit
    
End Sub
```

It is not a loop, but you can probably easily abstract from that.

Comment: Many thanks Gustav. That's what I wanted to do, but I wasn't sure how to achieve it. I'll have a look through your code and see if I can make mine work. Many thanks.